# Getting an array of blocks with the same id magento

Tags: magento

```
$id = 'unique_id_block';
    $cmsBlockModel = Mage::getResourceModel('cms/block');
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block');

    $cmsBlockModel->load($block, $id);
```

I have the code above to return an a block object with the id called unique_id_block .

How is this possible to this to return an array of blocks because I may have more than 1 block with the same ID but with different store views.

Comment: at the moment this only returns 1 object, but in fact there is 2 in the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all blocks with the same identifier using a collection...

```
$id = 'unique_id_block';
$blockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', $id);
```

You can then iterate over this collection as you would do an array:

```
foreach ($blockCollection as $block) {
  //...
}
```

Since your question asks to have these as an array though, you can also convert the collection to an array and grab its items as in the following:

```
$id = 'unique_id_block';
$blockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', $id)
    ->toArray();

$blocks = $blockCollection['items'];
```

But unless there is a good reason for this, i would stick with the first example.

Comment: Calling getResourceModel directly to get a collection is, IMO, a bad habit. As a model can specify it's collection object instead of using the conventional one, you can end up mistakenly assuming all models MUST use the same class name format for collections.  Once you do that, you open yourself up to bugs due to your assumptions.  It's better to call getModel() and then getCollection() as that will properly ask the model what the correct collection object should be.

Comment: You are correct, by using 'collection' for the resource collection name, there is definitely an assumption of convention - particularly when dealing with known, core classes as we are doing in this question.  Regardless though - I have updated the answer for you :)

Comment: Based on the original question asking for an array of blocks, I would suggest using getItems() instead of toArray() as the former will return an array of block objects and the latter will also turn your blocks into basic arrays instead of objects.  Of course, in that case you can just treat the collection as an iterator as it implements IteratorAggregate and Countable.

Comment: Hi Lee - Maybe I interpreted the question differently - you are probably correct in your interpretation though so thanks for pointing that out.